# Quando dou zoom meu rodapé fica atrás da div conteúdo

Tags: css

Queria saber como eu faço para que meu rodapé fique logo abaixo do conteúdo quando eu de zoom.

No momento está assim com zoom: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img924/4070/7FllwV.jpg

Tirando zoom :
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img924/9828/204jVK.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title> Home  </title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/estilocadastro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/animate.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>




    
    <div id="container">
    
    <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="copyrigth">
    
            <a href="#"> Copyrigth - 2016 Todos Direitos Reservados.</a>
            
        </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="cadastro">
    
        <div id="divcadastro">
        
        <form action="Cadastrado.php" method="POST">
        
        <div id="textocadastro">Cadastro</div>
            
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" class="nome" id="nometeste" style="display:none" >
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" class="nome" id="nometeste" required>
            
            <input type="text" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome" class="sobrenome" style="display:none">
            <input type="text" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome" class="sobrenome" required>
            
            <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Email" class="login" style="display:none">
            <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Email" class="login" maxlength="40" required>
            
            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" class="senha" style="display:none">
            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" class="senha" maxlength="30" required>
        
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="botao">
            
        </form>
        
        </div>
        
    </div>





</body>
```

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
```

}

```
body, html {

width: 100%;
height: 99%;
font-family: Comic Sans MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
background:url("../Images/WEB-ARTE2.png") fixed no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

}

## cadastro {

```
position: absolute;
top: 70px;
left: 50%;
width: 1343px;
height:  500px;
padding: 20px;
margin-left: -700px; /* por causa do posicionamento absoluto temos que usar margem negativa para centralizar o site */
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
z-index: 5;
box-shadow : 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

}

## divcadastro{

```
height: 500px;
width: 550px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
margin-left: 350px;

z-index: 10;
```

}

.login{

```
height: 40px;
width: 350px;
border: black solid 1px;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 150px;
border-radius: 3px;
```

}
.login:focus{

```
border: 1px solid #00FBF6;
```

}

.senha{

```
height: 40px;
width: 350px;
border: black solid 1px;
position: absolute;
top: 250px;
left: 150px;
border-radius: 3px;
```

}

.senha:focus{

```
border: 1px solid #FB00F9;
```

}

```
.botao{ 

border: none;
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
position: absolute;
top: 360px;
margin-left: 250px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
box-shadow: 1px 10px 19px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

}

```
.botao:hover{
    
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    
    
}

.nome{
    
    
height: 40px;
width: 350px;
border: black solid 1px;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 150px;
border-radius: 3px;

}
.nome:focus{
    
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
    
}

.sobrenome{

height: 40px;
width: 350px;
border: black solid 1px;
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
left: 150px;
border-radius: 3px;    
}
.sobrenome:focus{
    
    border: 1px solid #0105FB;
    
}

#textocadastro{
    
    
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    left: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder{

color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
position: absolute;
margin-left: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 5px;
}

#copyrigth{
    
    
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    /*vertical-align: bottom;    
    display: table-cell;*/
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    color: white;
    min-height: 3%;
    
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    
        
}
#copyrigth a{
    
    text-decoration: none; color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    
}
#copyrigth a:hover{ color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);}

#top{
    
    height: 39px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    color: white;
    min-height: 3%;
    padding-top: 7px;
    
    box-shadow: 5px 5px  10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    
}
```

Comment: Thales pode disponibilizar todo o HTML e CSS que tem ?

Comment: Atualizei o código

Answer (score 1):

Vai no css da DIV que está com o formulário (cadastro) dentro, e lá você acrescenta:

```
z-index: 1000;
```

Assim irá fazer com que a div que está segurando o conteúdo (Formulário de Cadastro) Vai ficar por cima do rodapé.

Comment: Acho que não me expressei bem, o problema é que o rodapé esta entrando no conteúdo em vez de ficar abaixo. Se eu colocar o z-index ira ficar em cima do conteúdo da mesma maneira

Comment: Um exemplo mais pratico seria o rodapé desse site, quando tiro o zoom ele fica 100% da tela quando eu dou zoom ele não entra no conteúdo

Answer (score 0):

Olha cara, arriscando um palpite deve ser por conta do:

```
position: absolute;
```

Na "divcadastro".